# how to initialize an attribute of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Metric class:

```
class Metric < ApplicationController

  attr_accessor :capability, :behavior

  def initialize(family_id)
    @capability = 5
  end 
end
```

In a controller I do:

```
metrics = Metric.new(222)
```

Then I try to get the capability attribute with:

```
puts metrics.capability
```

but I get an error:

```
NoMethodError Exception: private method `capability' called for #<Metric:0xa7bb4b0 @capability=5>
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Are you sure that `ApplicationController` has no method with such name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to inherit from `ApplicationController`. Stop inheriting it, it will start working.

If you want to initialise the attribute in all actions, all you have to do is this

```
class Metric 

  attr_accessor :capability, :behavior

  def initialize(family_id)
    @capability = 5
  end 
end


 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :initialize_metric_attribute

   def initialize_metric_attribute
     @capability = Metric.new(10)
   end
 end
```

Edit based on comment: 
You are inheriting from  `ApplicationController`. It should only be inherited only when you want to write some `action`. For writing `custom classes`,you dont need to do anything. If required you can inherit `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Since, you are have `initialize` method in your class `metric` class, you dont even need `AR`.

> Why it worked ?

We have just used `before_filter` callback which initialize your attribute. its Simple Ruby and Rails concept.

Comment: Probably there is a reason for that.

Comment: explained, let me know if you have any question.